# Access browser in centos minimal

Tags: php, linux, browser, centos7

How can I access a web browser in centos minimal 7 to try running my php on server? Centos doesn't seem to come with even yum repo to install lynx or any other CLI browsers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okie I tried **curl** ip_address:port & it worked. I can atleast check for th php output in CLI. :)